# How to set Nodata value into zero

Tags: function, matlab

I have a question. How can I set null value into 0 on an image. Is there any way to do this in matlab. The image type is float-point, 32 bit, tif format. Null value (Nodata) of this image is -3.4028234663e+038. So the number is out of range of float-point. So I wanna replace those values with 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can find all the elements to replace by:

```
idx = (I == x); % # x is the "null" value
```

where `I` is your image and `x` is the desired value to replace (in your case, that is the "null" value). However, a more practical syntax would be using a certain threshold value instead of the exact value:

```
idx = (I > y);  % # y is a value much lower than x
```

Now `idx` holds the logical indices of the elements you want to zero out. After you obtain `idx`, just do:

```
I(idx) = 0;
```

P.S
In practice, you can do achieve the same result without creating a temporary variable `idx`, like so:

```
I(I > y) = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you, EitanT. The first way to replace them into 0 worked well. Second way replaced the other values (not null value) into 0.